# Registration form Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular, registration

I am new in angular 2, and I need to make form for registration. Form fields are:Firstaname, lastname, sername, password, repeat password, email.Also need to make validation for fields and when is submit on sing up button, need to send in json format {{username: username, password: password, email: email, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname}.

If anyone can help, I would glad to see answer!

Comment: Start here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[for more code check this working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/huRHRz?p=preview)**

```
this.registrationForm= fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,  emailValidator])],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required],
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required]
    }, {validator: matchingPasswords('password', 'confirmPassword')})
```